Yaw incrase slowly without moving the sensor
I try to use MPU9250 and MPU6050 ... The problem is just with Yaw, I don t understant why the value of yaw increase slowly even I don t move the sensor , I tryed to control with just Gyroscope and with Gyroscope and Magnetometer, final : another problem; so , is possible to get value of Yaw just using Gyroscope ? I saw is possible using with Intrrupt mode but also, didn t see any problem using just gyroscope ( form other people , YT etc )
Code:
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <Wire.h>

int mpuAccGyro = 0x68;                                 // Daca conectam ADO la 5V => vom avea adresa 0x69; daca nu, vom avea 0x68

// ! Gyroscop
float x_gyro, y_gyro, z_gyro, er_x_gyro, er_y_gyro, er_z_gyro;
// ! Rol , Pitch , Yaw
float AngleRoll_acc, AnglePitch_acc, AngleRoll_gyro, AnglePitch_gyro, roll , pitch, yaw ;
// ! Count Error
int num_acc, num_gyro, num_mag;
// ! Real time Count
float previousTime , currentTime, elapsedTime;
uint32_t LoopTimer;

void acc_gyro_mag ();

void setup() {
  // ! ESP32 1
  Serial.begin(115200);
  pinMode(2,OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(2,HIGH);
  delay(100);
  digitalWrite(2,LOW);

  // ! Gyro_Mag_Acc Config
  Wire.setClock(400000);    // Communication with all registers of the device is performed using either I2C at 400kHz
  Wire.begin();
  delay(250);               // Da timp la MPU6050 sa porneasca

  // ! Start Power Mode acc_gyro
  Wire.beginTransmission (mpuAccGyro);
  Wire.write (0x6B);
  Wire.write (0x00);
  Wire.endTransmission ();
  delay (10);

  delay(100);
  digitalWrite(2,HIGH); // !!! Calibrare EFECTUATA CU SUCCES !!!
  LoopTimer=micros();
}

void acc_gyro_mag_calib ();

void loop() {
  acc_gyro_mag();

  Serial.print ("Yaw value : ");
  Serial.println (yaw);

  //while (micros() - LoopTimer < 4000);
  //LoopTimer=micros();
}

void acc_gyro_mag ()
{
    // CONFIG General ; citire date de la senzor
  Wire.beginTransmission (mpuAccGyro); 
  Wire.write (0x1A);              
  Wire.write (0x01);                       // Singele measurement           
  Wire.endTransmission ();

  // GYROSCOP
  // Config Gyro
  Wire.beginTransmission (mpuAccGyro);
  Wire.write(0x1B);                    // Gyro Config Full scale
  Wire.write(0x8);                     // Selectare Bit4 (1000)
  Wire.endTransmission();
  // Gyro OUT
  Wire.beginTransmission (mpuAccGyro);
  Wire.write(0x43);                    
  Wire.endTransmission();
  Wire.requestFrom(mpuAccGyro,6);       // Selectare Hex de la 43 la 48 (6 in total)
  int16_t X_gyro = ( Wire.read() <<8 | Wire.read () ) ; // Citeste primele 2 registre pentru X; 
  // https://invensense.tdk.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/PS-MPU-9250A-01-v1.1.pdf
  x_gyro = ((float) X_gyro / 65.5);                            // Gyro_sensevity (LSB/(*/s))                  
  int16_t Y_gyro =  ( Wire.read() <<8 | Wire.read () ) ;
  y_gyro = ((float) Y_gyro / 65.5); 
  int16_t Z_gyro =  ( Wire.read() <<8 | Wire.read () ) ;
  z_gyro = ((float) Z_gyro / 65.5);
  // Real time count
  previousTime=currentTime;
  currentTime = millis ();
  elapsedTime = (currentTime - previousTime) / 1000;

  yaw = yaw + z_gyro* elapsedTime ;
}

I tryed all example of any code but I didn t get anithing ...
